# How to give NOT NULL as a parameter value in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

I'm trying to build a report where i try to filter values from a table by their close dates (datetime). So far i've created a parameter called @closeDateParam and i want users to select between 2 options, one of them refers to NULL and other one refers to NOT NULL.

my sql is something like this,

```
select * from TABLE1 where TABLE1.CLOSED_DATE = @closeDateParam
```

and i've specified values for this parameter in parameter properties as
(Null) and (NOT Null)

but it seems it does not work for me.

I'd be grateful for any help since i'm a newbie at using ReportBuilder. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please be more specific if you want to do this inside SSRS report or inside sql query ? On SSRS you need to use IsNothing function to handle nulls.

Comment: I want to do this inside SRSS report as a parameter. There will be two options, one is for getting the null records and the other option is for the not null records